# Is this file safe to commit to a respository or will it reveal my secret key?

Tags: flask, secret-key

I am currently trying to set up a secure configuration for my secret key.  I am following "Flask Web Development" by Miguel Grinberg.  In chapter 7, he provides the example of a config.py file.

In the config.py he defines the SECRET_KEY in the following way:

```
Class Config:
   SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'hard to guess string'
```

From my understanding, this file functions by first looking in the ENV for the value of 'SECRET_KEY' and failing to find one, provides a default secret_key with 'hard to guess string'.

Is this file safe to commit to a repository or will it undermine the encryption of cookies if I dont have an ENV-defined secret_key?

If I deployed this code and ran the web app with a ENV not including 'SECRET_KEY', people would be able to find 'hard to guess string' in my repository use that secret_key, right?

Comment: Yep, that's about right

Comment: Thanks @JiříBaum, so what was the author's intention? To use this config file but not commit it to a respository?

Comment: It's a tutorial; the author needed to write it in such a way that it would "just work". In a production setting, you need to configure your SECRET_KEY in such a way that it's not in a repo (or in a published book). You probably have several such secrets - this one, database password, probably others. Managing secrets is a whole other chapter...

Comment: Note that you need to manage secrets not just in production, but also throughout your dev, test and deployment pipeline; you'll need a (probably different) secret when running the app locally for dev, when running it in unit tests and integration tests, and then when running it in production

Comment: Got it, thanks @JiříBaum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way to avoid making a mistake is to remove `or 'hard to guess string'`, then ensure that the `.env` in your production environment has the production secret key, and the `.env` in your develoment environment uses a separate secret. You'll want add `.env` to your `.gitignore` so that it doesn't accidentally get checked in.

If you haven't gotten there yet, Grinberg adds `python_dotenv` in chapter 15.